# refresh a tab in angular ui

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

Am creating tabs dynamically using angular-ui-bootstrap,using directives i can make the template for tabs and loading the contents inside it using ng-include.Now my requirement is to reload this content when i click the refresh button in tab header.

```
tabsApp.directive('apptabs', function () {
    return {
            restrict:"E",
            scope:{
                tablist:'=',
                ondelete:'&'
            },
            templateUrl:"././static/jslib/appTemplate/tabs-directive.html",
            controller:function ($scope, $attrs) {
                $scope.deleteTab = function (id) {
                    $scope.ondelete({id:id});
                }

            }
        };
    })
```

template for tabs

```
<tabset>
  <tab ng-repeat="tab in tablist"
        heading="{{tab.title}}" active="tab.active" disabled="tab.disabled">
    <tab-heading>
    <i class="{{tab.iconCls}}"></i>
      {{tab.title}}
      <a class="button small" ng-click="deleteTab(tab.id)" href='' ><strong>x</strong></a>
      <a class="button small"  href='' ><strong>refresh</strong></a>
    </tab-heading>
     <ng-include src="tab.page"></ng-include>
  </tab>
</tabset>
```

any idea?

Answer (score 1):

To handle page refresh. I think you need to use a `service` to get hold on currently active tab or you need to add an extra parameter in your URL and keep on changing that as and when user clicks on tab.

Answer (score 1):

I have done exactly this. You need a function that returns the current active tab:

```
 $scope.active = function () {
        return $scope.tabs.filter(function (tab) {
            return tab.active;
        })[0];
    };
```

I then have a button that calls a refresh function:

```
<button ng-click="refresh()" class="pull-right btn btn-success">Refresh</button>
```

Then all the resfesh function has to do is rebind the data for the current active tab:

```
 $scope.refresh = function () {
        var activetab = $scope.active();

       //call web service here or whatever to
       //get tab contents passing current active tab then bind result
       //to any scope binding that you have for the current tab

       $scope.tabcontent = results; //etc...
    };
```

Hope this makes sense.