How can I force the reload of parent component from its child component?
This app was written using Angular 17 (standalone) and Ionic 7. Tab1Page ("cards") is the parent and ItemCardComponent is its child (a Swiper carousel of ion-cards which values are recovered from a Firestore Database):
export class Tab1Page {
 slides: itemData[] = [];

 constructor(public itemService: ItemService) {
    this.ionViewDidEnter();
 }

 ionViewDidEnter() {
  this.itemService.getThings().subscribe((items: itemData[]) => {
   const extra: itemData = {
        user: '',
        name: '',
        picture: ''
   }
   items.unshift(extra)
   this.slides = items;
  });
 }
}

From ItemService:
getThings(): Observable<itemData[]> {
    const itemsRef = collection(this.firestore, 'userItems');  
    const q = query(itemsRef, where('user', '==', this.auth.currentUser!.uid) );
    return collectionData(q, { idField: 'id'}) as Observable<itemData[]>;
  }

NOTE: First card ('extra') is always blank and it's used for data input.
first card of the Swiper carousel
When a new card is saved ("setThing" is called from the child "ItemCardComponent"), data is stored as a new item to 'userItems' (Firestore collection).
From ItemService:
setThing(thingUnit: itemData) {
  thingUnit.user = this.auth.currentUser?.uid;
  const itemsRef = collection(this.firestore, 'userItems');
  return addDoc(itemsRef, thingUnit); 
}

I think I get to a correct diagnose of the issue, but I'm stuck on what to do to solve it.
Everything works fine when it come to save (and recover) data from Firestore. Except for the carousel view, which goal was to be updated in real time, but currently requires a manual refresh of Tab1Page to show the new slide. Obviously, It doesn't update because the saving event (that occurs in child) doesn't trigger any kind of change to the slide array (that relies on the load/reload of parent). The calls that updates this.slides array with the values from "items" will only happen when the constructor and ionViewDidEnter() run.
What commands should I use to force a refresh of Tab1Page (parent), taking into account that I'll need to run it from the ItemCardComponent (child), together with the card saving/editing functions?
I guess if that should be other solutions to this, because I understand that this current code implies too much calls to Firebase and that's not the optimal scenario.

This is how I got the app to have "acceptable" behavior for the moment:
When new items are saved, child component emits the event (as it was well suggested by @SwissCodeMen) to call a function in the parent component .
Decorator declaration:
@Output() reloadParentEmitter = new EventEmitter<boolean>();

Triggering the event from the child's "saveItem" function:
this.reloadParentEmitter.emit(true);

"Capturing" the event from the parent side (tab1.page.html):
<app-item-card (reloadParentEmitter)="reloadItems($event)"></app-item-card>

And, finally, running the "routing approach" from the function that's called in "tab1.page.ts" (parent):
reloadItems(reloading: boolean){
this.router.navigateByUrl('blankCanvas', { skipLocationChange: true }).then(() => {
  this.router.navigate(['reload']);
});}

As I just wanted a reload of the 'ion-tab' (parent) where the 'app-item-card' (child) is nested, all that I needed was a quick navigation to any other path and back again to the original one. So I generated a blank page with the same background of the entire app and pointed my first jump to it:
this.router.navigateByUrl('blankCanvas', { skipLocationChange: true })

And than, back to the original path, where data is already updated:
this.router.navigate(['reload'])

To achieve the correct routes I edited path values in "app.routes.ts":
{path: 'reload', loadChildren: () => import('./pages/private/tabs/tabs.routes').then((m) => m.routes)},
{path: 'blankCanvas', loadComponent: () => import('./pages/private/shared/components/blankCanvas/blankCanvas.page').then( m => m.BlankCanvasPage)}

And, in "tabs.routes.ts", I added a copy of the original tab path, renamed to 'reload':
{path: 'reload', redirectTo: '/tabs/tab1', pathMatch: 'full'}

As I said, that's none but the "acceptable" solution I got to, right now. But I will keep investigating and I'm sure I'll find a better approach to it.

With the little code-snippet and your error description in the question, I came up with the following workaround/solution. I wrote it down as a kind of pseudocode
There are several ways to send data between components. Since you are dealing with parent and child components, the easiest way to do this is via @Output() (child -> parent) and an event emitter.
Add the @Output() property as class variable to the child -component:
@Output() saveNewItemEvent = new EventEmitter<void>();

Now execute this event, by saving new items in child-component:
this.saveNewItemEvent.emit();

In parent component, where you call child-component, you can now listen to this event:
<app-child-component>
    …
    (saveNewItemEvent)="reloadItems($event)"
    …
<\app-child-component>

Within reloadItems() in parent-component, you can reload/load datas now to achieve the new saved items, where you needed after new savings changes in child-component

Thanks, @SwissCodeMen. I agree that an Output is my better option to call a function on parent side. And although I'm used to this decorator, I really thank you for answering and propose something. English is not my mother tongue and I probably explained badly what I really meant to ask, which was "which command(s) force a reload of the 'current tab' ". I kept investigating and found this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23458655/refresh-a-tab-in-angular-ui, which seems to fit my needs.. but now I'll have to find out how to "translate" from jQuery to JS... I'll let you know if I succeed.

How do you load the tabs? Probably with a get-call from the backend that accesses the database. After a new tab is saved, this get-call needs to be triggered. And with my code in this answer, this is possible if the get call is in the parent-component and the addition of the tab is done in the child-component. If that is not what you want/need, you need to share more code and specify the question. I also think this angularjs answer does not give you the solution you want

You were right, that angularjs answer was not helpful. I finally adopted an approach that uses routes. I'll post a self-response below to share it (although I still think there must be a better way to reload/render the elements saved to a Firestore collection).
